# gvim latex interface not appearing after latex-suite installation

Tags: vim, gvim, latex

I have been installing gvim with the latex-suite plugin on a laptop running an Ubuntu 13.10 OS. The installation of gvim worked, but I'm not sure if the latex-suite installation did too.

According to [the documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-inserting-template.html), some TeX specific menus must appear, but I can't see them.

What I did during the installation process was:

1. To install the latex-suite plugin I typed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vim-latexsuite
   ```

The installer worked successfully.

2. I then configured the `~/.vim/.vimrc` file as explained in [the documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download),
3. I then typed

   ```
   sudo vim-addons -w install latex-suite
   ```

as said in the `README.Debian` file located at `usr/share/doc/vim-latex-suite`
Apparently, that worked successfully, but when opening a tex file with gvim i get this message:

```
(gvim:3675): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(gvim:3675): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(gvim:3675): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(gvim:3675): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
```

And, as I said, any TeX specific menu is appearing there.

If any one of us can help me, it would be nice.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the isse adding the lines in step 1 to another `vimrc` file located in the `usr` directory. Settings in the `etc` directory were supposed to be appended and eventually overwrite the setting in the `usr` directory, and for some reason that was not the case...

With these settings I get the same warning opening vim, but latex-suite runs properly.